# &quote transforms to &amp;quot;

Tags: c#, xml, app-config

I'm trying to store my entity framework connection strings on app.config file.

```
            string con = "metadata=res://*/OtomasyonDB.csdl|res://*/OtomasyonDB.ssdl|res://*/OtomasyonDB.msl;provider=FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient;provider connection string=&quot;Database=" + Application.StartupPath + "\\" + "DATABASE\\" + textEdit10.Text + "\\" + DateTime.Now.Year + "\\DATABASE.FDB" + ";data source=localhost;user id=SYSDBA;password=masterkey;server type=0&quot;";
```

Here is my connection string when i save into app.config file

```
    metadata=res://*/OtomasyonDB.csdl|res://*/OtomasyonDB.ssdl|res://*/OtomasyonDB.msl;provider=FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient;provider connection string=&amp;ampquot;Database=C:\Users\Erdal\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MUHASEBESON\DXApplication4\bin\Debug\DATABASE\444\2017\DATABASE.FDB;data source=localhost;user id=SYSDBA;password=masterkey;server type=0&amp;quot;
```

Its look like this `&quot;` is going to `&amp;quot;`

True connection string must look like this.

```
    metadata=res://*/OtomasyonDB.csdl|res://*/OtomasyonDB.ssdl|res://*/OtomasyonDB.msl;provider=FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient;provider connection string=&quot;Database=C:\Users\Erdal\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MUHASEBESON\DXApplication4\bin\Debug\566\2017\DATABASE.FDB;data source=localhost;user id=SYSDBA;password=masterkey;server type=0&quot;
```

I tried to string replace function but im sending true connection string it translating into this when its saving to app.config file.

And this is my saving code

```
     string con = "metadata=res://*/OtomasyonDB.csdl|res://*/OtomasyonDB.ssdl|res://*/OtomasyonDB.msl;provider=FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient;provider connection string=&quot;Database=" + Application.StartupPath + "\\" + "DATABASE\\" + textEdit10.Text + "\\" + DateTime.Now.Year + "\\DATABASE.FDB" + ";data source=localhost;user id=SYSDBA;password=masterkey;server type=0&quot;";
            asd.ConnectionString = con;
            configuration.AppSettings.CurrentConfiguration.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings.Add(asd);
            configuration.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
            ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
```

Comment: *How* are you saving that string into the config file? Please show ([edit] your post) that code.

Comment: @HansKesting i edited it, sorry.

Comment: A guess: try `\"` instead of `&quot`. It seems that saving that connection string escapes the string - which now extra escapes the `&`

Comment: @HansKesting it worked, thank you. solved.